# How is this true in case of proportionality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a \propto t$ (directly proportional), then $a = Kt$.

If $a = 6Kt$ , then also $a \propto t$.

Why are these two results same?

Displacement of a particle is proportional to the cube of time elapsed. How does the acceleration of the particle depends on time obtained is?

This is the question from where my doubt arose.

Comment: The first result is $a=Kt$, and the second result is $a \propto t$. They are not the same.

Comment: @peterwhy It is 6Kt

Comment: @user279337 What is the definition of "directly proportional"? Start from there

Comment: $a\sim t$ means there exists a $K$ so that $a=Kt$ but there is nothing indicating that that just what the constant $K$ is.  $6K$ is also constant.  This is a bit like saying an elephant is big and that means an elephant weighs 13,000 pounds.  But a humpback whale weights 66,000 pounds. And it is big also.  Why are these results the same.

Comment: @fleablood Yeah so.They are not right.

Comment: @OttavioBartenor As one amount increases . Another amount increases at same rate.

Comment: If $Income=\$15.75 \times hours$ then $hours$ is directly proportional to $Income$ because there is a constant $K$ so that $Income= K\times hours$ (In this case $K$ is the salary rate of \$15.75 per hour).  But there is no requirement for *what* the constant is.  ... $Distance = 30\times hours$.  In this case the distance traveled is directly proportional to hours traveled, because there is a constant $K'$ so that $Distance=K'\times hours$. But $K=15.75$ and $K'=30$ and $K\ne K'$. But that doesn't matter. The constant thing for one proportion doesn't have to be the same as another proportion.

Comment: Of courseThey are right!!  An elephant *IS* big.  And a whale *is* big.  They are just big in different ways.  And if $a = K\cdot t$ then $a\sim t$ because $K$ is a constant.  ANd if $b = 6Ks$ then $b\sim s$ because $6K$ is a constant.  $a\sim t$ mean there is a constant. It could be $K$, it could by $6K$, it could be $\sqrt[39]{e^{K\pi}}$.  It doesn't matter *what* the constant is.  It just matters that $a=\text{some constant}\cdot t$.  That means $a\sim t$.

Comment: Ok.Thank you.Reading it made it easier to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When we say $a \propto t$ (directly proportional) , it means a = constant*t. By convention, the constant is called K but it could be anything else; it could be D OR Y or anything. Thus when we say a = 6Kt, the new constant is 6K which can be renamed to another constant D. So if we say D= 6K, then a = Dt and as D is a constant a is still directly proportional to t.

Answer (score 0):

If $a$ is directly proportional to $t$, then  $A = Kt$, for some constant $K$ (which we call the *constant of proportionality*).

If $a = 6t$, then observe that $a$ is directly proportional to $t$, with $K = 6$.

[Perhaps you are confused as to how mathematical definitions work? The if in a definition is typically an if and only if, which can certainly be confusing at first!
]

Comment: I did an editing mistake.It is 6Kt

Comment: Ok, take your constant $K' = 6K$, argue as above.

Comment: Ok.Getting it now.@bounceback